# Slow Visual Studio 2015 Performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've downloaded VS2015 for desktop for personal use. However, the IDE is incredibly slow, I have to wait for around 3 secs to type. I can't even rename a folder. When I have VS open, it's really slow to browse the internet as well.

I believe my system meets all the system requirements, based on [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#5).

My system is running on:

- Win8 Pro (Dual Boot, installed in Macbook Pro)
- 8 GB of RAM
- i5 @2.30GHz
- 300GB HDD

I've done the ff TS, based on my research but none of them works:

- change the source control from TFS to none (since I dont use one anyway).
- remove the git DLL files that has something to do with Git.
- uncheck automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance.
- uncheck auto updates.
- downgrade to VS2012, issue still persist.
- sent a feedback to Microsoft VS but I havent receive any.
  Im not familiar with Resharper or NTVS yet so most likely I haven't installed them. Ive check in the control panel its not there.

Is there anything else I can do to rectify the issue?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed at all? By that I mean any installed by you, I know that some of the functionality in VS2015 is installed as extensions so there will be some listed there, but have you added any on top of that? If so, which ones?

Comment: How much of that HDD is full? Is the ram working correctly? I'm not sure this is a suitable question for SO, possibly superuser but even then it might be off-topic.

Comment: Ask this question in Super User side, which for stuff like this. It is part of StackOverflow family.

Comment: Check in your Task Management -> Processes what is time consuming? Also try to disable the resharper. It's also being know that visual studio works badly on Macs

Comment: Try watching it in the resource monitor. Is it disk bound? CPU bound? If really desperate, you could learn to make/read an xperf trace :)

Comment: "Dual Boot, installed in Macbook Pro" how? (Apple does not always play nice with Windows ...)